# How to specify parameter on blade to access the foreign key between table columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-query-builder

I am a newbie in Laravel. Right now, I have the problems
with the solution that I using between the relationship of the 2 tables below.

I have 2 tables that are jobs and users.

The first one I have 4 roles in this User Table.

**User Table**

| id | user | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | UserA | Admin |
| 2 | B | UserB | Vendor |
| 3 | C | UserC | Salesperson |
| 4 | D | UserD | Customer |

**Job Table**

I stored the user->id in **created_by** and **updated_by** columns

| id | name | created_by | updated_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Job2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | Job3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Job4 | 4 | 2 |

I have to show them on createjob.blade.php

For example,

Job 1

**First drop-down**
Who is the Salesperson? (show all salespersons here)

**Second drop-down**
Who is the Vendor? (show all vendors here)

**and I also store who created this job which anyone can create jobs (4 roles in User Table).**

[image]

I encounter the problem that is the Job Dashboard showing the wrong user->name when I try
to show who is the one that created the job (updated_by is also incorrect).

[image]

**Here is Job Model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\user', 'created_by');
}
```

**I try to show who created the job by put created_by in the user's function ( I just try to do this one first)**

```
public function vendors(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\user', 'vendor_id');
}

public function salespersons(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\user', 'user_id');
}
```

**Function Index**

```
public function index(){

    $users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('role','vendor')
    ->where('role','salesperson')
    ->where('role','admin')
    ->get();

    return view('admin.jobDashboard', ['users'=> $users])
    ->with('jobs',JOB::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25))
    ->with('typecategories',TypeCategories::all())
    ->with('salesperson',DB::select('select * from users where role = ?', ['salesperson']))
    ->with('vendors',DB::select('select * from users where role = ?', ['vendor']))
    ->with('provinces',Province::all())
    ->with('districts',District::all())
    ->with('subdistricts',SubDistrict::all())
    ->with('images',Images::all())
    ->with('status',Status::all());
}
```

**Function Edit**

```
public function edit($id){

    $jobs=Job::find($id);
    $categories = Categories::all();
    $selectedCategories = $jobs->categories;

    $shop_product_type_categories = ShopProductTypeCategories::all();
    $selectedShopProductTypeCategories = $jobs->shop_product_type_categories;

    $users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('role','vendor')
    ->where('role','salesperson')
    ->where('role','admin')
    ->get();

    return view('admin.editJob',[
                'jobs'=> $jobs,
                'categories' => $categories,
                'selectedCategories' => $selectedCategories,

                'shop_product_type_categories' => $shop_product_type_categories,
                'selectedShopProductTypeCategories' => $selectedShopProductTypeCategories,

                'users'=> $users,
                ])
                ->with('typecategories',TypeCategories::all())
                ->with('salespersons',DB::select('select * from users where role = ?',['salesperson']))
                ->with('vendors',DB::select('select * from users where role = ?', ['vendor']))
                ->with('provinces',Province::all())
                ->with('districts',District::all())
                ->with('subdistricts',SubDistrict::all())
                ->with('images',Images::all())
                ->with('status',Status::all());

}
```

**Here is the page that I fond the problem**

I don't know the right way to show the create_by column of the Job Table and then
access the relationship column that is the name of the user.

```
<div class="title mb-3">Created_by:&nbsp;{{$jobs->created_by->users['name']}}</div>
```

[image]

If I use $jobs->['name'] the system doesn't know which is created_by or updated_by.
How to specify created_by and updated_by here?

Thank you in advance. If you help me to solve this you are my hero who save my life.
[image]

p.s. If I type something wrong please forgive me. I didn't use English in my daily life.

Comment: Question is too large... Did you define your sql relationship on your migration correctly?

Comment: I am not sure about it...I have created_by and updated_by in the Job Table and to store the id of the user. The problem is when I use $jobs->user['name'] I have to use this parameter 2 times on the blade. The first one for "created_by" to get the User Id that stored inside Job Table to compare with the id in the User Table and the last one for "updated_by" I think that if I can specify one for access created_by and another one for updated_by the problem will be solved.